# SAS Parameter logconfigloc and conventional log output

Tags: sas

I got the task to log user access to datasets in certain libraries.

To solve this I use the SAS Audit logger, which already provides the desired output.

To get this desired output, i use the start parameter logconfigloc with the following XML-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<logging:configuration xmlns:logging="http://www.sas.com/xml/logging/1.0/">

   <!--  Log file appender with immediate flush set to true -->
   <appender name="AuditLog" class="FileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="logconfig.xml.win.audit.file.xml.log"/>
      <param name="ImmediateFlush" value="true" />
      <filter class="StringMatchFilter">
        <param name="StringToMatch" value="WORK"/>
        <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="false"/>
      </filter>
      <filter class="StringMatchFilter">
        <param name="StringToMatch" value="Libref"/>
        <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true"/>
      </filter>
      <!-- The DenyAllFilter filters all events not fullfilling the criteria of at least one filters before -->
      <filter class="DenyAllFilter">
      </filter>
      <layout>
         <param name="ConversionPattern"
                value="%d - %u - %m"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>

   <!--  Audit message logger -->
   <logger name="Audit" additivity="false">
      <appender-ref ref="AuditLog"/>
      <level value="trace"/>
   </logger>

   <!--  root logger events not enabled  -->
   <root>
   </root>

</logging:configuration>
```

My Problem is, that by using the logconfigloc parameter, the log parameter is not working any more hence I get no "conventional" SAS log.
I allready tried to enable the root logger, but it´s output only looks similar to the original logfiles but has some diffrences.

Is there an (easy) way to get the "conventional" SAS log in addition the to the afforementioned special access logging output?

Kind Regards,
MiKe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to the question how to obtain the conventional log.
For this purpose the SAS logger named "App" with message level "info" can be used.

So the following XML does the trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<logging:configuration xmlns:logging="http://www.sas.com/xml/logging/1.0/">

   <appender name="AppLog" class="FileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="D:\Jobs_MK\SAS_Logging_Facility\Advanced_Logging_Test_with_XML\logconfig_standard_log.log"/>
      <param name="ImmediateFlush" value="true" />
      <layout>
         <param name="ConversionPattern"
                value="%m"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>

   <!--  Application message logger -->
   <logger name="App" additivity="false">
      <appender-ref ref="AppLog"/>
      <level value="info"/>
   </logger>

   <!--  root logger events not enabled  -->
   <root>
   </root>

</logging:configuration>
```